# Best answer contest: Fourth quarter of 5777

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is currently **over**.

1. **Nomination** - ending October 15, 2017

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Tamuz - Elul, 5777 (from June 25, 2017 through September 20, 2017)** are eligible.

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - October 15 - October 22, 2017

   On October 15 (after the holidays), this post will be edited to indicate that the Voting phase has begun, and the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag will be added.

   During this phase, everyone will be invited to vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on October 22, 2017. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: Locked to end voting

Answer (score 4):

[Chaim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/3388/chaim)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85017/759) to [Why was the second Beit HaMikdash destroyed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85013/759) is impressively comprehensive. It has sources, quotations, translations and summaries from a wide variety of rabbinic literature.

Answer (score 4):

[Oliver's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85650/8775) regarding the possible halakhic issues involved in attending an intermarriage. It is quite comprehensive; indeed the first answer that is comprehensive to an important question asked almost 6 years ago and has had five other answers.

Answer (score 3):

[DoubleAA's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83707/472) to [Who inherits if a man and wife die together?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83705/who-inherits-if-a-man-and-wife-die-together) not only answered the question but taught and demonstrated a method to answer "what's the halacha?" questions that arise from talmud study.  Not only did I get my answer, but I got tools I and others can apply to future questions.

Answer (score 3):

[DonielF's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84086/9682) to [Why are some dates off by one day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84071/9682). It took a challenging question, worked on the math behind it, and showing how the mistakes made along the way actually helped to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Micha Berger's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83841/2) to [Is there any halachik basis for using "the big two" (shabbat and kosher) as a criteria for frumkeit?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83816/is-there-any-halachik-basis-for-using-the-big-two-shabbat-and-kosher-as-a-cr) addresses the question directly and compellingly by clearly laying out authoritative sources. It also includes worthwhile bonus material that complicates the message in the main answer with equally-authoritative sources. Finally, it sets an example for care for intellectual honesty, in that it acknowledges which aspect of the question it's not addressing and why, it provides an important Halachic caveat in the main answer, and it makes a clear distinction between the main answer and the bonus material, while explaining how the latter complements the former.

Answer (score 0):

[TrustMeI'mARabbi's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11433/trustmeimarabbi) answer to [Rebbe Nachman on Connecting to Tzaddikim and Teffilah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83924/rabbi-nachman-on-connecting-to-tzaddikim-and-tefillah/84585#84585). While the language of the Likutei Moharan initially did not sit well when first reading (as written in the question),the short and simple insight of Noam Elimelech cited will likely serve to be helpful for those foreign to such a concept enabling them to understand the idea in a reasonable, effective manner.