# Best Answer Contest winners! Third quarter of 5777

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and Yeyasher Kochachem to the co-winners of the [Best Answer Contest for the third quarter of 5777](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4310/best-answer-contest-third-quarter-of-5777)!

Here are the original citations, both submitted by DoubleAA:

- [Lee](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2091/lee)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83382/759) to [How many halachot are detailed in the Mishneh Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34248/759) exemplifies doing original work and research to deal with a problem, not just searching Google for someone else's work. That's something we should encourage here on Mi Yodeya.
- [Tookie345](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/14809/tookie345)'s [self answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82959/759) to [Which sins are specifically punished with drought?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82949/759) involved an OP taking info from a comment ("Check out Taanit 7b") and not only looking it up for himself but following up and sharing with the community with a well written answer. That's something we should encourage here on Mi Yodeya.

The winning entries will split the 300-point bounty prize evenly.

[Best answer contest: Fourth quarter of 5777](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4361/best-answer-contest-fourth-quarter-of-5777), covering Tamuz through Elul, 5777 (from June 25, 2017 through September 20, 2017), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please enter it!