# Best Answer Contest winners! Fourth quarter of 5777

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and Yeyasher Kochachem to the co-winners of the [Best Answer Contest for the fourth quarter of 5777](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4361/best-answer-contest-fourth-quarter-of-5777)!

Here are the original citations, submitted by DoubleAA and mevaqesh, respectively:

- [Chaim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/3388/chaim)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85017/759) to [Why was the second Beit HaMikdash destroyed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85013/759) is impressively comprehensive. It has sources, quotations, translations and summaries from a wide variety of rabbinic literature.
- [Oliver's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85650/8775) regarding the possible halakhic issues involved in attending an intermarriage. It is quite comprehensive; indeed the first answer that is comprehensive to an important question asked almost 6 years ago and has had five other answers.

The winning entries will split the 300-point bounty prize evenly.

[Best answer contest: First quarter of 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4410/best-answer-contest-first-quarter-of-5778), covering Tishrei through Kislev, 5778 (from September 21, 2017 through December 18, 2017), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please enter it!